# Prove whether the set of vectors is linearly dependent or linearly independent (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, logic

If vectors  $\alpha _{1} ,\alpha _{2} ,\alpha _{3}$ are linearly dependent, vectors  $\alpha _{2} ,\alpha _{3} ,\alpha _{4}$ are not linearly dependent. Can $\alpha _{4}$ be linearly represented by $\alpha _{1} ,\alpha _{2} ,\alpha _{3}$?

My question is why can't the method in my answer below be used for the proof? If this proof is incorrect, then where is it wrong?

$\because \alpha _{1} ,\alpha _{2} ,\alpha _{3} $ is linearly dependent
$\therefore k_{1}\alpha_{1}+k_{2}\alpha_{2}+k_{3}\alpha_{3}= 0 $,$\exists k_{i}\neq 0 (i\in \left\{1,2,3 \right\})$
$\therefore k_{1}\alpha_{1}+k_{2}\alpha_{2}+k_{3}\alpha_{3}+k_{4}\alpha_{4} = 0 $,$\exists k_{i}\neq 0 (i\in \left\{1,2,3,4 \right\})$,
it means just $k_{4}=0$
$\therefore \alpha _{1} ,\alpha _{2} ,\alpha _{3},\alpha _{4} $is linearly dependent
$\therefore \alpha _{4}$ can be linearly represented by $\alpha _{1} ,\alpha _{2} ,\alpha _{3}$

Comment: My issue is you skip massive steps in concluding that $\alpha_4$ can be represented by the other three. You would perhaps be able to exhibit an explicit representation if that were the case, but the only conclusion I can draw from your work probably involves a division by zero. If the calculation is less obvious than "solve for $\alpha_4$", you should elaborate upon it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second line is not very well written; you seem to be saying that because $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ are linearly independent, then whenever $k_1\alpha_1+k_2\alpha_2 + k_3\alpha_3=0$ there must exist some $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ with $k_i\neq 0$. This because of how you placed the existential quantifier. That is incorrect.

Instead that line should real that "There exist $k_i$, $i=1,2,3$, *not all equal to zero*, such that $k_1\alpha_1+k_2\alpha_2+k_3\alpha_3=0$.

Similarly, your third line is not properly justified, though you could say that because of the previous line, you have $k_1\alpha_1+k_2\alpha_2+k_3\alpha_3 + k_4\alpha_4=0$, with $k_1,k_2,k_3$ as before, and $k_4=0$. (You can't conclude that in any such expresson $k_4$ is *always* zero, which is again how what you write can be interpreted).

But your final line is a complete non-sequitur. You are asserting that $\alpha_4$ is a linear combination of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$. Why? Usually, you go from a nontrivial linear combination equal to $0$ to an expression of one vector in terms of the others by picking a vector with a nonzero coefficient in the expression. But here you have
$$0\alpha_4 = -k_1\alpha_1 - k_2\alpha_2 - k_3\alpha_3,$$
since you explicitly said the coefficient of $\alpha_4$ was going to be $0$. So how do you conclude from this that $\alpha_4$ is a linear combination of $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$?

(As to actually answering the question, let me ask you something: what happens if $\alpha_1=\mathbf{0}$?)

Comment: "But what I still don't understand is, based on the definition of linear dependence: 'There exist ki, i=1,2,3, not all equal to zero, such that k1α1+k2α2+k3α3=0,' then α1, α2, α3 are linearly dependent. So from the previous sentence, it is clear that when k4=0, ki, i=1,2,3,4, are also not all equal to zero, and they also make k1α1+k2α2+k3α3+k4α4=0. Why can't we then say that α1, α2, α3, α4 are linearly dependent?"

Comment: @ranli you can, but that isn't the question. The question is whether $\alpha_4$ is a linear combination of $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$. If it were, they wouldnall be linearly dependent. But it is possible for four vectors to be dependent and the fourth one **not** be expressible in terms of the other three. Consider the case where $\alpha_1=\alpha_2+\alpha_3$, for example. Or worse: the case where $\alpha_1=\mathbf{0}$.